# Converting ISO 6709 Formatted GPS Coordinates to Decimal Degrees in R

Tags: r, gps, iso

We have a piece of equipment that outputs its GPS coordinates as numeric values to file in an [ISO 6709](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709) lat/lon format of Lat = ±DDMM.MMMM & Lon = ±DDDMM.MMMM

Are there any packages with functions (or custom functions) in R that will convert this to a Decimal degrees format? (ie: ±DD.DDDDDD & ±DDD.DDDDDD)

An example would be that lat & lon (2433.056, -8148.443) would be converted to (24.55094, -81.80739).

Comment: Not directly of interest to your question, but there's a whole system in R that can convert from lat/long to various projections.

Comment: Thx for the comment. I looked at the "MapProj" & "MapTools" packages, but didn't see where they are able to accomplish the above. If they can, please do tell.

Comment: I believe the proj4 package has some facilities as well.  It's been a while since I've done this stuff, but I remember there being an embarasssment of riches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read in the values from the file using something like `read.csv` or `read.delim`.

Then to convert from DDMM.MMMM and DDDMM.MMMM you could use something like this (of course modify as needed for the form of your input/outputs):

```
convertISO6709 <- function( lat, lon ) {
    # will just do lat and lon together, as the process is the same for both
    # It's simpler to do the arithmetic on positive numbers, we'll add the signs
    #  back in at the end.
    latlon <- c(lat,lon)
    sgns   <- sign(latlon)
    latlon <- abs(latlon)

    # grab the MM.MMMM bit, which is always <100. '%%' is modular arithmetic.
    mm <- latlon %% 100

    # grab the DD bit. Divide by 100 because of the MM.MMMM bit.
    dd <- (latlon - mm)/100

    # convert to decimal degrees, don't forget to add the signs back!
    out_latlon <- (dd+mm/60) * sgns
    return(out_latlon)
}
```

Comment: Nice work - didn't know about the "sign" function, was trying to implement that with an if statement and <0 logic.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant PHP code, but it does work:

```
function convertISO6709($coord)
{
    $abs_coord = abs($coord);
    $sign = ($abs_coord == $coord) ? 1 : -1;
    $m = 2;
    $dlen = 2;
    $s = 0;
    $seconds = 0;
    switch (strlen($abs_coord)) {
        case 4 :
            break;
        case 5 :
            $dlen = 3;
            $m = 3;
            break;
        case 6 :
            $s = 4;
            break;
    }
    $degrees = substr($abs_coord, 0, $dlen);
    $minutes = substr($abs_coord, $m, 2);
    if ($s != 0) {
        $seconds = substr($abs_coord, $s, 2);
    }
    return ($degrees + ($minutes / 60)  + ($seconds / 3600)) * $sign;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar issue getting coordinates from FedEx WS. I used this function to get the values from a string like +19.467945-99.14357/:

```
function convertCoordISO6709($coord)
{
  //$coord example
  //$coord = +19.467945-99.14357/

  $returnArray[0] = 1;//result non 0 means error
  $returnArray[1] = 0;//Lat
  $returnArray[2] = 0;//long

  $coord = trim($coord,"/"); //Strip / sign
  //look for + - sign
  $lat_sign = substr($coord,0,1);  //strip and save the first sign (latitude value)

  $sub_coord = substr($coord,1,strlen($coord));

  if(count(explode("+",$sub_coord)) == 2) //Second value is + for the longitude
  {
    $coords=explode("+",$sub_coord);
    $returnArray[0] = 0;
    $returnArray[1] =  $lat_sign.$coords[0];
    $returnArray[2] =  "+".$coords[1];    
  }
  else //Second value is - for the longitude
  {
    $coords=explode("-",$sub_coord);
    $returnArray[0] = 0;    
    $returnArray[1] =  $lat_sign.$coords[0];
    $returnArray[2] =  "-".$coords[1];      
  }


  return $returnArray;
}
```